# PHP - on click function convert value

Tags: php, html, onclick, modal-dialog

i have a problem with onclick function that convert value when passing it

this is my variable
$info['IDMIGLIORAMENTO'] -> 00000071

and this is the code that call the onclick function

```
        echo  "</td><td>
               <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='chiusurapresa(" . $info['IDMIGLIORAMENTO'] . ")' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#close'><i class='far fa-check-square'></i></button>
               </td></tr>";
```

at the end of the page i have a little javascript

```
function chiusurapresa(idchiusura) {
    $("#op_chiusura").val("");
    $("#id_miglioramento").val(idchiusura);
    $("#formchiusura").off('submit'); //some other things.... }
```

in my page i have a little modal with a form inside it and i'm trying to pass the value 00000071 to the modal

```
            <form role="form" action="update_chiusura.php" method="post" id="formchiusura">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="id_miglioramento" name="id_miglioramento" autocomplete="off" />
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="op_chiusura" name="op_chiusura" placeholder="Inserisci operatore" autocomplete="off" />
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="notechiusura" name="notechiusura" placeholder="Inserisci eventuali note" autocomplete="off" />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Chiudi</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salva</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

the problem is that the value 00000071 is converted to number '57' when on click pass it to the function
and i dont know how to handle this problem

i say converted because if i try to pass value 00000072 it became '58'

in attach a snapshot of the google chrome inspect element

[inspection element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ5wf.png)

can someone help me?
thanks in advance

Comment: JavaScript thinks this is an octal number: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#octal_numbers You need to pass this value as a string inside your onclick attribute, not a number.

Comment: If you want to pass string '0000071', add quotes around.

Comment: how can i add qoutes.. if i add quotes i get error

Comment: try to do it as @pavel said or convert it in your function "chiusurapresa" to string

Answer (score 1):

Convert the value to a string before passing to input field.
$("#id_miglioramento").val(idchiusura.toString);

Comment: this doesn't work because it's already 57 when i do it